# COUNTIFS: Calculating percentage with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm currently trying to solve for the **% of Team Users on Mobile.** I'm not quite sure as to why it's automatically turning into a percentage but here is my formula in the cell that says 600.00%

```
=COUNTIFS(K$5:K$108, E4, L$5:L$108, L$7)
```

- K5:K108 refers to the column that says "Team".
- *L5:L108* refers to the column that says *"Capture Mode"*.

I know that this formula simply counts the numbers of Team's Users on Mobile. How can I change this to a percentage? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The % of team users on mobile = the number of mobile users on the team / the total number of team members.

You already have the numerator and just need the denominator, which would just be a simple `COUNTIF(K$5:K$108,E4)`.